# I wanna make a UDP communication between two or more computers

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-10.04

I need to make a connection through wireless or LAN. I have done this on Windows (VS2008 C#, Sockets), but not on Linux (`Ubuntu 10.04`). I have installed `mono`, and I can handle many things there, but it's speed is unacceptable for my 600MHz processor, so I decided to move on C++, but I'm new to C++ and I'm not familiar to many of it's headers. Is there any header or library which can do that for me?

Answer (score 1):

How the actual connection is done (if wireless or cable) should be up to the system; if you want to use sockets, I suggest reading of [beej guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) , it contains everything (or so) you need to know. It's C mainly, but reusing it for C++ needs no effort.

Comment: Thank u a lot answering my question ...
ok, i saw that book, nice but it's something hard for me to do that,
I know that i should put more energy to learn it, but if there were a
library or sth which i could use ...

Comment: try serveez http://www.gnu.org/software/serveez/ but it could sound hard too, requiring a little bit of studies and work

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html), this way you can share at least the code between linux & windows. The overhead is not that big compared to naked sockets and you have the benefit of better semantics. Many parts of code from boost have flown into standard C++ so the code is of rather high quality.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i need. Thank you. I saw the online documentation, it seems it can also solve my other issues about multithreading.
Unfortunately the sourceforge.net has blocked our country(Iran) so i cannot download the boost library. is there any suggestion downloading it's last release 1.43?

     again thanks for everything